# GStreamer-1.0 Yocto : record RTSP stream to h264 avi

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, video-capture, yocto

I'm trying to record a RTSP stream into a avi file using `avimux`
On my dev computer it works, but not my target generated using `yocto`.
I use `avimux` to be able to play the recorded stream during while recording or when killing the recording process in order to avoid

> Header atom 'mdat' has empty length

and to be able to play the record after a hard shutdown

The pipeline I use :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e uridecodebin uri=rtsp://root:bni@192.168.0.5/axis-media/media.amp ! x264enc speed-preset=1 ! avimux ! filesink location=file.avi
```

The logs returned on the Yocto target using `GST_DEBUG=2`:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
>   Progress: (open) Opening Stream
>   Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://root:bni@192.168.0.5/axis-media/media.amp
>   Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
>   Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
>   Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
>   Progress: (open) Opened Stream
>   Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
>   New clock: GstSystemClock
>   Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
>   Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
>   Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
>   0:00:00.568731753   983 0xb690f0f0 WARN         rtpjitterbuffer /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/1.4.1-r0/gst-plugins-good-1.4.1/gst/rtpmanager/rtpjitterbuffer.c:185:rtp_jitter_buffer_set_clock_rate: Clock rate changed from 0 to 90000
>   0:00:00.651109657   983 0xb4e01e60 WARN                   libav /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-libav/1.4.1-r0/gst-libav-1.4.1/ext/libav/gstavcodecmap.c:2408:gst_ffmpeg_caps_to_pixfmt: ignoring insane framerate 1/0
>   Redistribute latency...
>   0:00:00.772074956   983 0xb4e01e60 WARN                  avimux /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/1.4.1-r0/gst-plugins-good-1.4.1/gst/avi/gstavimux.c:641:gst_avi_mux_vidsink_set_caps: refused caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, width=(int)800, height=(int)450, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1
>   0:00:00.772219844   983 0xb4e01e60 WARN                  avimux /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/1.4.1-r0/gst-plugins-good-1.4.1/gst/avi/gstavimux.c:641:gst_avi_mux_vidsink_set_caps: refused caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, width=(int)800, height=(int)450, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1
>   0:00:00.772272716   983 0xb4e01e60 WARN                GST_PADS /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0/1.4.1-r0/gstreamer-1.4.1/gst/gstpad.c:3742:gst_pad_peer_query: could not send sticky events
>   0:00:00.772355744   983 0xb4e01e60 WARN                  avimux /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/1.4.1-r0/gst-plugins-good-1.4.1/gst/avi/gstavimux.c:641:gst_avi_mux_vidsink_set_caps: refused caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, width=(int)800, height=(int)450, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1
>   0:00:00.772479080   983 0xb4e01e60 WARN                  avimux /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/1.4.1-r0/gst-plugins-good-1.4.1/gst/avi/gstavimux.c:641:gst_avi_mux_vidsink_set_caps: refused caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, width=(int)800, height=(int)450, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1
>   0:00:00.772759088   983 0xb4e01e60 WARN                  avimux /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/1.4.1-r0/gst-plugins-good-1.4.1/gst/avi/gstavimux.c:641:gst_avi_mux_vidsink_set_caps: refused caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, width=(int)800, height=(int)450, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1
>   0:00:00.794258643   983 0xb690f0f0 WARN                 basesrc /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0/1.4.1-r0/gstreamer-1.4.1/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c:2933:gst_base_src_loop: error: Internal data flow error.
>   0:00:00.794332935   983 0xb690f0f0 WARN                 basesrc /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0/1.4.1-r0/gstreamer-1.4.1/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c:2933:gst_base_src_loop: error: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
>   ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1: Internal data flow error.
>   Additional debug info:
>   /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0/1.4.1-r0/gstreamer-1.4.1/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(2933): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1:
>   streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
>   Execution ended after 0:00:00.414329589
>   Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   Setting pipeline to READY ...
>   Setting pipeline to NULL ...
>   Freeing pipeline ...

The important log is :

> gst_avi_mux_vidsink_set_caps: refused caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, width=(int)800, height=(int)450, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1
>   0:00:00.772272716   983 0xb4e01e60 WARN                GST_PADS /home/thomas/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0/1.4.1-r0/gstreamer-1.4.1/gst/gstpad.c:3742:gst_pad_peer_query: could not send sticky events

Do you have any idea, what can be missing on my Yocto target ?
Thank

Comment: Are both using the same version or gstreamer. Also can you try a different container (e.g. mp4mux), since h264 in avi is not a perfect couple.

Comment: It works with `mp4mux` using this pipeline:

Comment: It works with `mp4mux` using this pipeline:
<pre>gst-launch-1.0 -e uridecodebin uri=<URI> ! x264enc speed-preset=1 ! mp4mux fragment-duration=100 streamable=true faststart-file=<FILE>.mp4 ! filesink location=<FILE>.mp4</pre>
But now I have issues to stream this recorder over RTSP using `gstrtspserver`
<pre>( filesrc location=<FILE>.mp4 ! decodebin name=d low-percent=40 use-buffering=true ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=fastdecode speed-preset=ultrafast ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )</pre>
Which is working on my dev computer but not on the `yocto` target

Comment: For making your pipeline more reliable you can have "videoconvert ! h264parse" before the h264 encoder. But as ensonic suggested H264 in AVI is not a good combination.